# Checkbox issue on chrome

Tags: html, css, checkbox, input, custom-element

Hei guys, i have a little problem with customized checkbox. Everyhting is OK in Mozilla but when it comes to Chrome it works differently.As you see below checkboxes in column 1 works fine when they are checked but in other columns it just gives background when it is checked. Where I gave same css to all checkboxes. It looks different in mozilla, i mean it works well .

```
   .listContent input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
}
.listContent input[type=checkbox] + label {
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.listContent input[type=checkbox] + label ~ label {
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

.listContent input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    display: block;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}
.listContent input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
left: -19px;
top: 3px;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    background: url('../../jpgs/checked.png') no-repeat center center;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0.7) !important;
    opacity: 0;
}
.listContent input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
.listContent input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: #64bd5f;
}
.listContent input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
    opacity: 1;
    background: #64bd5f;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In first of all try to reset css with this: http://cssreset.com

Answer (score 0):

Check this website for CSS checkbox styling: http://www.csscheckbox.com/. Basically, for checkbox styling, you set a background image to the checkbox that contains the checked and unchecked state and manipulate the background position of that image based on whether the box is checked or not.

For example:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
                        padding-left:21px;
                        height:16px; 
                        display:inline-block;
                        line-height:16px;
                        background-repeat:no-repeat;
                        background-position: 0 0;
                        font-size:16px;
                        vertical-align:middle;
                        cursor:pointer;

                    }

                    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
                        background-position: 0 -16px;
                    }
```

I see that you've done something similar and you are manipulating opacity instead of background-position. I think background-position might be easier to implement and its essentially the same thing as using a spritesheet.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, 'overflow:hidden' thing was affecting it.Thank you all